# Mean Value Theorem and infinity

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be the function $f: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$; $x \mapsto \sqrt{1 + x}$. We note that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + x}} < \frac12 + \varepsilon$ since $f'(x)$ is monotonic and decreasing for $x_1 < x_2$ and $f'(0) = \frac12$.

So if we were working with a closed interval we'd know that

$$
\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|} < \frac12 + \varepsilon, \quad \varepsilon > 0
$$

But our function isn't defined on a closed interval. I'm wondering if I can truncate the interval and somehow preserve the results? Especially since $f'(x)$ has its max at $f'(0)$.

The ultimate goal is to show that $f(x)$ is a contraction and the MVT looked like a nice way to go about it until I realized the interval didn't fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove your claim (the displayed inequality) on an interval $0 \le x < y < \infty$, simply apply the MVT on the interval $[x, y]$. Also, I think you've got a sign error on your epsilon, or maybe that it doesn't need to be there at all:
\begin{align}
f'(x) 
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1+x}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+x}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{ 1+\frac{x}{2}-\ldots} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}( 1-\frac{x}{2}+\ldots) \\
&\le \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

More simply, $1 + x \ge 1$, so $\sqrt{1 + x} \ge 1$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \le 1$. Hence your whole expression is no greater than $\frac12$.